# Saving a SVG, background image is left out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I'm currently working with D3 to draw a line chart on an svg. I want to save the svg, which works fine. The line chart gets saved, but the background image I have added, is left out. I just get a plain color background.

Here is a short example on how I add the background, and how I save the svg. It's a simplified example, without a line graph and with an image found online. Originally the background image is loaded from a folder on the web server. The result however, is the same. No background image when I save it. There is no css involved in this.

http://jsfiddle.net/uphytob3/3/

This is the script part of it.

```
$("button.save_button").click(function() {

    if ($(this).attr("value") == "export_image") {
    save_svg();
  }
});

var canvas = d3.select("#container")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("height", 440)
        .attr("width", 503);

canvas.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "#FAFAFA");

canvas.append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_800_800/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANNAAAAJDU2MmE4ODEwLTQ1YTAtNGFjNi1iNmM5LTY4NGFiN2I0NmI5Yg.png")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 503)
    .attr("height", 440)
    .attr("opacity", 0.5);

function save_svg() {
    var html = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

    var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.height = 700;
    canvas.width = 1400;

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image;
    image.src = imgsrc;
    image.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

        var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "test.png";
        a.href = canvasdata;
        a.click();
    };
}
```

I have tested adding the image again when I save the svg, but that didn't work because it either was hidden behind the line chart, since the line chart isn't transparent, or it was on top of the line chart, hiding parts of it.

This is a modified save_svg() function.

```
function save_svg() {
    var html = d3.select("svg")
        .attr("version", 1.1)
        .attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg")
        .node().parentNode.innerHTML;

    var imgsrc = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);

    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.height = 700;
    canvas.width = 1400;

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var image = new Image;
    image.src = imgsrc;

    var bg = new Image;
    bg.src = "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_800_800/AAEAAQAAAAAAAANNAAAAJDU2MmE4ODEwLTQ1YTAtNGFjNi1iNmM5LTY4NGFiN2I0NmI5Yg.png";

    image.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        context.drawImage(bg, 0, 0); 

        var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.download = "test.png";
        a.href = canvasdata;
        a.click();
    };
```

Any ideas on how to get the background image in the saved image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is unclear.  You talk about "no background", but when I try your code, I get a PNG with the grey (#fafafa) background.

So perhaps you are actually talking about the picture you have added on top?  The one from media.licdn.com?

The reason you are not getting that picture in your saved PNG file is because of privacy restrictions in the browser.  SVGs loaded as images *must be self contained*. They can't refer to third party objects.

You are loading the SVG as an image by loading it as a DataURI into a `new Image`.  Loading the SVG that way means the external file linked by the `<image>` is ignored.

Ways you can work around this would be:

1. convert your third party image to a Data URI and include it in the SVG that way.  By doing that, it is no longer an external resource.
2. when saving the SVG, paint it onto the canvas yourself first.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated the question to make it clearer. Since jsfiddle doesn't allow uploading of images, I had to use an external image to make an example. Originally I'm using an image located in an img folder on the web server. Would it still be considered external?

Comment: Yes. When I say "external" I am talking about external *to the SVG*.